# Использование декоратора

Tags: python, ооп, solid, декоратор

Есть класс `Scrappy`, у которого есть метод `parse`.

```
class Scrappy:
    def parse(self):
       pass
```

Есть `Crawler`, который осуществляет действия со `Scrapper`. При этом, для того, чтобы была отказоустойчивость, вводится специальный метод `__scrappy_decorator`, который, в случае отказ `Scrapper.parse()` перезапускает метод `parse()`:

```
class Crawler:

    def __init__(self, max_attempts):
        self.__scrappy = Scrappy()
        self.__max_attempts = max_attempts

    def __scrappy_decorator(self, fn):
        count = 0
        e = None
        while count < self.__max_attempts:
            try:
                return fn()
            except e:
                count += 1
        raise e

    def run(self):
        self.__scrappy_decorator(lambda: self.__scrappy.parse())
```

Мне кажется, что в данном случае напрашивается декоратор (`__scrappy_decorator`) для метода `parse`. Но это не представляется возможным в силу того, что `Scrappy.parse()` ничего не должен знать о том, что его могут вызывать несколько раз. А значит с точки зрения логики мы не можем прикрепить к нему декоратор.

Есть ли способы, как обойти эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы перепишете `__scrappy_decorator` как декоратор и навесите его через `@`, то исходная функция и не будет знать, что ее обернули в декоратор (в этом смысл декоратора: исходная функция выполняет свои действия и ни знает ни о чем вокруг, а вокруг нее еще строится какая то логика - логирование, перезапуск и тд - логика декоратора). Если вы имеете ввиду, что проблема в том, что иногда необходимо вызывать именно **исходную** функцию, то делайте примерно как сейчас: `new_func = decorator(fanc)`, тогда new_func - декорированная функция и есть доступ к исходной фунции.

И лямбда в последней строке наверное избыточна, вы же передаете функцию, а `parse` и есть функция: `self.__scrappy_decorator(self.__scrappy.parse)`

```
def decorator(fn):
    def new_func(self, max_attemps):
        count = 0
        e = None
        while count < max_attempts:
            try:
                return fn(self)
            except e:
                count += 1
        raise e
    return new_func
```

Comment: Это всё классно, но мне важно параметризовать декоратор при инициализации. А если я это сделаю как говорите Вы, то ничего не выйдет

Comment: @hedgehogues почему не выйдет?  `new_func = decorator(fanc)` так не выйдет потому что вам при этом надо прокинуть в декоратор значение?

Comment: Как мне при создании объекта `Crawler`, задать `__max_attempts`?

Comment: @hedgehogues Как я понимаю вы через конструктор задаете  `self.__max_attempts`, а затем в `run` надо вызвать декорированный `new_parse`? Вроде `new_parse = decorator(self.__scrappy.parse, max_attempts=self.__max_attempts)`

Comment: Странно... обычно, декотораторы явно не оборачивают функции

Comment: @hedgehogues Обычно нет, Вы правы, в измененном ответе декоратор можно использовать как `@` и вызывать с параметрами..наверное так лучше. Я просто путаюсь в какой момент вы хотите его параметризовать